# How to copy a jar-file from one docker stage to another with docker onbuild copy?

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I'm beginner with Docker, and I'm trying to build an image in two stages.
The first docker-file is uploaded to docker-hub and has the following structure:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine 
ONBUILD COPY app.jar /app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
```

The second dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:4.7.0-jdk8-alpine AS build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN ./gradlew build

FROM <repo>/<first_docker_file>:1.0
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app.jar
```

So I need to build my project -> generate jar file -> copy it to the root directory of the second docker stage of the second docker file.
I need to copy generated jar-file from the first stage to the root directory of the second stage, cause "ONBUILD COPY app.jar /app.jar" is triggered and is waiting for app.jar file in the root directory. The code I have provided in the second file does not work. I also can't change the code of the first docker-file. Do you have any ideas, how can I make it work and what should I change in the second docker file ?

Comment: What you've described cannot work as-is.  Q: Could you update your post to explain *why* you need a staged build?  The "requirements" behind your build chain?

Answer (score 0):

From the [ONBUILD reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild) i understand that the `ONBUILD` commands are inserted directly after the `FROM` command when inheriting from it.

As i understand it this means your `app.jar` needs to exist when the `FROM` command is issued, i.e. your effective Dockerfile would look like

```
FROM <repo>/<first_docker_file>:1.0
COPY app.jar /app.jar
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app.jar
[...]
```

which obviously wouldn't work.

It seems like your first dockerfile is not meant to be used in a staged build, you need to get the `app.jar` in the working directory when issuing the build on the first dockerfile, i.e. by compiling inside a container and copying out your `app.jar` to your first dockerfile location and then build it.